# Having trouble connecting redux to react and dispatching actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new to redux so I might be missing something here...

**redux/reducers/schools.js:**

```
export const SET_SELECTED = 'schools/SET_SELECTED';

const initialState = {
  selected: {},
  schools: []
};

export default function schools(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SELECTED:
      return {
        ...state,
        selected: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function setSelected(school) {
  return {
    type: SET_SELECTED,
    payload: school
  };
}
```

**containers/Search.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setSelected } from '../redux/reducers/schools';
import SchoolCard from '../components/SchoolCard';

class Search extends Component {
  setSelectedSchool(school) {
    this.props.dispatch(setSelected(school)); // Error here
  }

  renderShools(schools) {
    return schools.map(school => {
      return (
        <div className="column is-8 is-offset-2" key={school.emis}>
          <SchoolCard school={school} setSelected={this.setSelectedSchool} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="columns">{this.renderShools(this.props.schools)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  schools: state.schools.schools
}))(Search);
```

When `setSelectedSchool()` in `Search.js` runs I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined...

What am I doing wrong / what am I missing?

Comment: you have not mapped reducer to props hence it is undefined

Comment: @KOTIOS how do I do that? In my example in `Search.js` at the bottom you'll see I used `export default connect(....` ... is this not correct? I'm able to read the store state fine, it's dispatching actions that I don't quite understand here.

Answer (score 1):

Code below represents an example how to map to props and then call dispatch :

```
import { addItem } from  './actions/items';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       // some more tags
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addItem: () => {
      dispatch(addItem())
    }
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Incase you do not do `mapDispatchToProps` then this.props.dispatch will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default connect(state => ({
  schools: state.schools.schools
}),
(dispatch)=>{return {setSelected:(data)=>(dispatch)({type:"SET_SELECTED",payload:data})}}
)(Search);
```

You can give 2 objects to connect

```
1. mapStateToProps {
      schools: state.schools.schools
    }
2(dispatch)=>{return {setSelected:(data)=>(dispatch)({type:"SET_SELECTED",payload:data})}
```

You required dispatch (2) also in order to dispatch function 
So change last line to(where you use connect) to

```
export default connect(state => ({
      schools: state.schools.schools
    }),
    (dispatch)=>{return {setSelected:(data)=>(dispatch)({type:"SET_SELECTED",payload:data})}}
    )(Search);
```

and the function call to

```
 setSelectedSchool(school) {
    this.props.setSelected(school); // Error here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refract your code a bit

containers/Search.js

```
import  React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as schoolActions from '../actions/schoolActions; 
import SchoolCard from '../components/SchoolCard';

class Search extends Component {
  setSelectedSchool=(school)=> {
    this.props.setSelectedschool(school)
  }

  renderShools(schools) {
    return schools.map(school => {
      return (
        <div className="column is-8 is-offset-2" key={school.emis}>
          <SchoolCard school={school} setSelected={this.setSelectedSchool} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="columns">{this.renderShools(this.props.schools)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(
state => ({
   schools: state.schoolReducer.schools,

}),
{ ...schoolActions }
)(Search);
```

Create actions/schoolActions.js

```
export function setSelectedschool(school){
    return (dispatch)=>{
         dispatch({'SET_SELECTED',school})
    }
}
```

create reducers/schoolReducer.js

```
const initialState={
   school:[] //assuming it's an array
}
const schoolReducer =(state=initialState,action)=>{
   switch(action.type){
      case 'SET_SELECTED':{
          return {
              ...state,
              school:action.school
          }
      }
   }

}
```